# load a page inside a folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications

I have changed the name of codeigniter and placed htdocs  then in application folder I have created a new folder in that new folder again I created some folders for different web pages in each and every folder I added controllers,models,view  files. Now I want to access a controller file which is in the new folder.

I tried with default route but not working..Can anyone suggest

Comment: You've created a folder in your application folder and then added controllers to it?

Comment: yes , like shown here                                                                                 sample->application->newfolder->loginfolder->controllers->loginfolder.php

Comment: but why is there a need to add multiple folders and then have controllers there? Ain't the whole and sole purpose of codeigniter is to follow MVC structure which it already has? You can instead place all your controllers in application->controllers.

Comment: further, in application->config->routes.php you can use $route['default_controller'] = "yourcontroller.php" to redirect your application to the controller which should be executed first

Comment: I agree what you said. But I have seen somewhere like this pattern and that is worked. So to get the result in that pattern I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Create as many folders as you want inside the controller model and view folders in CodeIgniter and not outside them if you really want to organise them.

Remember to set base URL in application/config/config.php file and default router inside the application/config/routes.php file.

If you have problems please comment below describing errors.

Comment: Thank you James, I got the solution for my question. The required pattern is called hierarchical mvc structure( hmvc). and that is described clearly in the developers website i.e http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/

Comment: happy to hear that.